# Attempting to run pg_dump as user "postgres" returns error related to non-postgres user

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

When I try to run pg_dump as the user "postgres",

```
$ sudo -u postgres pg_dump <pg_dump arguments>
```

I receive the error

```
psql: FATAL:  role "username" does not exist
```

where "username" is my OS username (i.e., $USER).  It seems like if I were attempting to use pg_dump as myself, it would matter that there's no "username" role, but since I'm not, it shouldn't.  How do make pg_dump do something?  Postgres 9.4.8 on Fedora.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `export PGUSER=postgres`, then execute commands without specifying the OS user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running `pg_dump`, why does the error message say `psql`?

I'm guessing you are doing something like this:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump foo bar $(psql blurb blurgle)
```

or possibly this:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump foo bar | psql blurb blurgle
```

So you need to `sudo -u postgres` for both commands.

In any case, it sounds like you are looking in the wrong place for the problem.

Comment: Yes!  I overlooked that.  Thanks!